# Можно ли уже пользоваться CLANG?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Как я понял, GCC не поддерживает полностью стандарт C++11. Может, уже пора переходить на CLANG при программировании под LINUX?

Comment: * http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html
* https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Не вижу разницы.

Comment: Делаю в на языке CLANG rextester.com/LDZZP24517 - работает (как я понимаю, это под линукс), визуал с++ тоже компилит, а вот gcc не хочет... похоже, gcc отстаёт... (((

Comment: у меня clang также не собирает этот пример. Не реализовали просто поддержку codecvt в gcc.